# What PHP data structure suits the storage of web urls and descriptions etc?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, struct, associative

I want to store the following pieces of information in a structure or array of some sort in PHP;

- URL
- Title
- Description
- Rank

I want the data to be associative, that a particular URL refers to a Title, Description & Rank.

I want to be able to sort the data then by rank, then echo it in that order, with each element still being associated.

Should I use associative arrays? Structs? Or some other PHP data structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$urls["http://example.com"] = array(
    "rank" => 3,
    "title" => "abc",
    ...
)
```

and use `uasort` for ordering

Comment: Thanks, what type of data structure is that so that I can google it and research it further, associative array?

Comment: PHP arrays are ordered hash-tables. Check PHP docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: That's great, thanks. I will be able to sort those then by "rank" and use a foreach loop to echo them in that order I take it?
I will read up on PHP associative arrays now, thanks!

Comment: @sam yes, using the `uasort` function as I noted in my answer

Comment: I have the array created, and am reading data into it from the decoded json response, then var_dump'ing it succesfully, thanks!
Is there a way to access an individual entry now by its index?
I tried to var_dump($array[0]); with no success. Sorry for the very basic question.

Comment: @sam sure, you can access both keys and values by index using `array_keys` and `array_values` functions

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom class for this. For more information about php classes, visit [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: What is the point of introducing classes in this case? The task is to store and traverse data.

Comment: I may well use a class if I need to, I would go with associative arrays if they meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$data = new LinkData();

$data->set("http://stackoverflow.com/q/17406624/1226894", [
        "name" => "Data Structure",
        "rank" => 3
]);

$data->set("http://stackoverflow.com/", [
        "desc" => "Nice Site",
        "title" => "Stackoverflow"
]);

foreach($data as $v) {
    print_r($v);
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://stackoverflow.com/q/17406624/1226894
    [title] => 
    [rank] => 3
    [desc] => 
    [name] => Data Structure
)
Array
(
    [url] => http://stackoverflow.com/
    [title] => Stackoverflow
    [rank] => 
    [desc] => Nice Site
)
```

Class Used

```
class LinkData implements IteratorAggregate {
    private $data = array();

    function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->data);
    }

    function set($url, array $info) {
        $this->data[md5($url)] = array_merge([
                "url" => $url,
                "title" => null,
                "rank" => null,
                "desc" => null
        ], $info);
    }

    function get($url) {
        return isset($this->data[$key = md5($url)]) ? $this->data[$key] : [];
    }
}
```

Comment: @amartynov .. Educate me what is over complicated ??? URL can be as long as 2,048 ... using that as keys like your examples does not make sense and you need to check out the performance issue ...  anyway .. i know nothing